# Insert into domainevententry table and publish to kafka topic in axon framework

Tags: axon

I know automatic insertion happens to domainevententry table as soon as we do aggregatelifecycle.apply(event) in axon framework what action triggers an insert in domainevententry table and what triggers a publish to a kafka topic in axon framework and how can we control what values goes into domainevententry table

Comment: Can you clarify subject and post a clear question?

Comment: I know there are set of event store tables that axon framework povides like domainevententry, sagaentry and 3 other tables,I know that domainevententry tables stores all the domain events and axon framework does this insertion automatically withoout having us to write any specific insert queries, I just wanted to know at what point does this insertion happens and what triggers this insert into all the 5 event store tables, event store tables are domainevententry, snapshotevententry, associatedvalueentry, sagaentry and tokenentry. Let me know if I am still not clear

Answer (score 1):

Explaining this point by point, in full detail, would be a bit much to go over.
On top of that, like @Pipetus stated, it is still unclear what your intent is with this question. It's highly recommend to be as specific in your posts as possible, stated the problem space, where you are coming from and where you want to get too.

Regardless, pointers you can look for when it comes to "how does this work" are the (aggregate) `Repository` implementations, the options of `EventStorageEngine`s provided, the `UnitOfWork` used to deal with message transactions and the phases the `UnitOfWork` transitions.

In short, all of these are described in the [Reference Guide of Axon](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/). I'd recommend reading up here and updating your question accordingly so that more specifics can be provided to you.

Comment: Thanks @Steven,
the intent of the above question was just understanding the underlying behaviour/concept.

Comment: even after reading axon referecne guide the concept was not clear hence asked on this forum